# ImportError: /home/test/test_1.so: wrong ELF class from cython build

Tags: python, cython, elf, importerror

I have build `.so` in cython as the [tutorial](http://www.behnel.de/cython200910/talk.html) says( `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`).
On that system where i have build it is working fine; no `ImportError`; but when i have used it on other system it gives me an error msg as 
 `ImportError: /home/test/test_1.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

I think its a mismatch between 32bit and 64bit library; so how can i fix it while cythonizing it???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You need to rebuild the `.so` on a 64-bit system and make sure you always use the right version on the right system. It is practically impossible for cython to allow 32-bit libraries to be used on a 64-bit system and vice-versa, due to the differences in those architectures. You would have the same problem with e.g. Ruby FFI.

Comment: I have to rebuild it on 64-bit system; and now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't share the same binaries in different architectures. But as long as you have python and the required libraries installed on either system, you can just compile the .c file produced by Cython, and don't need to have Cython installed in other machines (ie, convert the .pyx to .c).